# How to get images from facebook album

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I have albumID,I did the following code but not able to get the result (photos).
I think m missing something in facebook.request

```
try {
             //wallAlbumID is variable having album id.
        response = facebook.request("me/album."+wallAlbumID+"/photos");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONObject json = null;
    try {
        json = Util.parseJson(response);
    } catch (FacebookError e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONArray photos = null;
    try {
        photos = json.getJSONArray("data");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int i =0; i < photos.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject a = null;
        try {
            a = photos.getJSONObject(i);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

looking for code in response.

Answer (score 2):

If you already know your Album ID, you don't have to add `me/albums/` to your request. Try this:

```
response = facebook.request(wallAlbumID+"/photos");
```