# How to pic album images from facebook account using facebook sdk and show in list view

Tags: android

I am working over an android application and i want to select images from facebook album(may be mine or friends) and want to show in list view. I am doing log in facebook using facebook sdk3.6. I have used many examples but still i have no result and this thing now irritating me because i have worked more than 2 days. I am new in android so please help me out.
Thanks.

links which i have used for login
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/

link which i have used for getting facebook frofile images.
[How to get images from facebook album](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198455/how-to-get-images-from-facebook-album)
[Getting images from facebook album?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565021/getting-images-from-facebook-album)

Comment: My problem has been solved using facebook fql query..